# Should I put these functions in a standalone .h file?

Tags: c++, function, class, scope, header

I have a project which includes 2 files: *main.cc* and *header1.h*. While *main.cc* instantiates a class "className" and calls the member functions of it, the header file includes definition of the class.

main.cc:

```
#include <header1.h>
int main(){
    className classobject();
    classobject.function1();
    ...
    }
}
```

header1.h:

```
class className{
   public:
   className();
   void function1();
   ...
};

double className::function1(){
    double function2(){
    ...
    }
}
```

With this, I met an error which says:"a function definition should not be placed before '{' token.

So I decided to put the definition of *function2* outside of the class, and put it in a standalone *.h* file. In that way, my project would include 3 files, namely: *main.cc*, *head1.h* and *function2.h* file:

main.cc:

```
#include <head1.h>
int main(){
className classobject;
void classobject.function1();
...
}
```

head1.h:

```
#include <function2.h>
class className{
double function2();
...
}
```

function2.h:

```
double function2(){
...
}
```

Although function2 can also be defined as the class member function so that it can be moved out of function1 while inside the class, I want to know whether the above mentioned treatment is leagal. Besides, does the creation of header files have some implicit rules established by usage (common treatment)?

Could anyone give some comments? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing function definition in header files in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453372/writing-function-definition-in-header-files-in-c)

Comment: I'd prefer making the fucntion2() the private member of the className.

Comment: Semicolon missing after class definition.

Comment: you should use a `.cpp` file for the definitions of the class methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem in your code that I see is that you define `className::function1` in a header, but forgot to declare it `inline`. The outcome is that you can only use the header in a single compilation unit <sup>†</sup>. That's a bad design. I recommend defining it in a source file instead.

Secondly, you try to define `function2` inside another function. That's not allowed and therefore you got a compilation error. You say that you decided to move it's definition outside the class, but it's definition was already outside the class definition. Moving the definition outside the definition of `className::function1` is indeed a correct choice.

If `function2` is reusable outside it's use in `className::function1`, then it's indeed a good idea and perfectly legal to declare it in a separate header. But just like `className::function1`, you're defining `function2` also in the header again and again without declaring it `inline` and therefore you will get in trouble if you try to use it in multiple compilation units. I recommend defining `function2` in a source file as well.

<sup>†</sup> If you include the header in multiple compilation units, then each of those compilation units will contain the definition of the function. The *One Definition Rule* does not allow defining a function in more than one compilation unit. Functions that are marked `inline` are treated differently. They may be defined in multiple compilation units as long as they have an identical definition in each.

Comment: Hi, @user2079303, thanks for your helpful answer. But what do you mean by saying I can only use the header file in a single compilation uinit? Could you please explain it with more details?

Comment: Besides, I have already declared the 2 functions inline using _void function1_ and _double function2_ in the class and class method respectively.

Comment: @David I added explanation for why the the lack of `inline` prevents the use of the header in more than one compilation unit. And no, in the code that you show in the question, you don't declare the functions `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in your `className.hpp`

```
class className{
   public:
        className();
   private:
       void function1();
};
```

Then in your `className.cpp`

```
#include"className.hpp"

className::className(){ /*defintion*/ }

void className::function1(){ /*definition*/ }
```

Then you could use a makefile in oder to compute the `className.o` file and link it to the main file.

If you want to define another function (like `function2()`), you can then define it the `className.cpp`

Comment: This question is more about what to do about `function2` then splitting the class in a header and cpp file.